# Is there any polynomial or factorials to represent this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, factorial

I want to represent these series as a single polynomial or a form of some factorials.

$k=1$

{$1,2,2$}

$k=2$

{$1,2,3,3,3$}

$k=3$

{$1,2,3,4,4,4,4$}

$k=4$

{$1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,5$}

Comment: Sorry, @Osama . I feel that what you said is impossible. For a sequence, one value of $k$ must yield just one value, but this one doesn't follow that norm. However, if $k$ is a common difference (as in an AP or GP, i.e., arithmetic progression or geometric progression) , things could have been easier.

Comment: Also, the sequence seems to be like this : you want the first value of the "sequence" to be $1$, the rest must increase by $1$ till the value is equal to $k +1$ , and then the last value must appear $k + 1$ times, right ?

Comment: Yes, that is right!

Comment: Well, then @Osama , I think you'd rather need a program (I am not an expert in this topic and hence only said my opinion. Maybe some experts will help you out. And I didn't vote your question down, so hope you won't feel bad. I like doubts ! :) ).

Comment: Or , a suggested thing is : the sequence must be an union of the set of natural numbers making $(k+1)!$ (each number less than or equal to $(k+1)$)  and a set containing the terms of an arithmetic progression $a_n = (k + 1) + 0$ in order from $n = 1$ to $n = k$.

Comment: In short, the set of the required sequence (let the set be $K$) is like this :                  $ K = \lbrace n : n \in \mathbb{N}, n | (k+1)!, n \leq (k+1) \rbrace \cup \lbrace(k+1),(k+1),\dots \text{k times} \rbrace $

Comment: Thanks . That is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coefficient of $x^{j}$ in

$$[x+2x^2+\ldots+(k+1)x^{k+1}][1+(k+1)x^{k+1}(1-x)]$$

where $1 \le j \le 2k+1$.

Comment: Yes. that is amazingly right. Can you explain how did you derive it?

Comment: By method of undetermined coefficients in the second factor.